# Resources for "non-computational" and "non-algorithmic" optimisation problems?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

I have seen on this site some nice recommendations on books of optimisation. Most of them and most of the books I find includes a lot of analysis of algorithms.

However, certainly there are plenty of optimisation problems in the world from which fruitful results can be obtained without computers (this does not mean algorithms has no role to play - I just mean without massive computation we can still get a lot of interesting things). **Some example includes Brachistochrone, economic model of new Keynsian investment and saving curves, and Bellman's equation for dynamical programming.** All these can be derived and used in many places without any algorithmic approach, for problems which are "nice".

I would be grateful if anyone can provide a reference for an optimisation book that **does not base heavily on algorithms** and preferably with many examples of applications. A problem collection is also very helpful.